# bind param usage on multiple values with single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO friend(`uId`,`friendId`) VALUES (?,?), VALUES(?,?)");
$stmt2->bind_param('ssss', $userId,$friendId,$friendId,$userId);
```

I expect it would insert 2 rows with the result

```
uId friendId
1    2
2    1
```

but it returned

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$a = '';
$b = '';

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO friend(`uId`,`friendId`) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt2->bind_param('ss', $a, $b);

$a = $userId;
$b = $friendId;
$stmt2->execute();

$a = $friendId;
$b = $userId;
$stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: @user3522457 you're using mysqli or pdo?

Answer (score 1):

INSERT takes only one VALUES clause, even if the VALUES clause includes multiple tuples.

```
INSERT INTO friend(`uId`,`friendId`) VALUES (?,?), (?,?)
```

But more importantly, you should *always* check the return value of `prepare()` because it returns **false** if there's an error in your query. Of course you cannot call a the `bind_param()` method on a false value, because false is not an object with methods at all.

Comment: I tried your format but how is the bind param look like? this $stmt2->bind_param('ssss', $userId,$friendId,$friendId,$userId);
doesn't work

Comment: Did you check for errors as I suggested? What error was output? See an example here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: yes I tried your answer but it return Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement